# Going from Activity A to B onClick and back to A if a condition have not been on B

Tags: android

I want to go from Activity A to Activity B `onClick` and back to Activity  A if a `condition` have not been on Activity B.

Activity A:

```
    onClick() {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_B.class);
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Activity B:

```
if (condition) {
   //code for return back to Activity A
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage \`startActivityForResult\` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Comment: You only need `if (condition) {
   finish();
}`  In this case

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going directly from Activity A to Activity B and want to get back to Activity A. I am assumimg that no other Activities are being called from Activity B then you just finish the Activity B inside your condition. It will automatically be returned to Activity A